# How to coexist dataflow sdk and aws sdk

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to write S3 custom sink by using Dataflow Java SDK.
Although AWS SDK uses httpclient4.5.2, Dataflow SDK still uses 4.0.1.
So it's conflict when I try to run the job.
I guess to upgrade the version of Dataflow's httpclient is the way to solve it.
How can I update it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpClient dependency comes via
Dataflow SDK 1.8.0 -> google-api-client 1.22.0 -> google-oauth-client 1.22.0 -> google-http-client 1.22.0 -> httpclient 4.0.1

According the the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/setup) for Google Http Client, it needs HttpClient 4.0.1 *or compatible*.

Which version of HttpClient is Maven resolving to? (See `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`.) If it's 4.0.1, you might be able to force 4.5.2, assuming they are compatible. (Semantic versioning would imply so.)